# Python: Check Number elements match exactly

Tags: python, list, integer, comparison

This seems to be simple, but maybe I've just had my head in it too long...
I have a list which contains six numbers:

i.e.
`mylist=[2,4,6,8,10,12]`

I just want to check if the list contains an exact sequence
i.e.
`if mylist == [1,2,3,4,5,6]:`

I've tried

```
if mylist == [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
if mylist == ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
if mylist == ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
```

None seem to work. I have another way of doing this with a for loop using the list.count() function, but I feel the above method would be better if possible. Can someone provide insight?

Thanks ;)

Comment: What did you think was wrong with `list == [1,2,3,4,5,6]`?

Comment: I have code inside the if statement that is not executing when the if statement is crafted like that i.e. if list == [1,2,3,4,5,6]: print("x")

Comment: "check if the list contains and exact sequence"... What do you want exactly?
Assert that mylist is exactly the same as the reference, or that all elements in mylist are in the reference, or that they are in the reference in the same order, but there may be other elements in the reference, or that the set of elements in mylist is equal to the set of elements in reference?

Comment: Yes, assert that myList contains [1,2,3,4,5,6]. Order is not really important as the list will be sorted anyway. So If I set the list to myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6] I want some code to execute if myList is set to this.

Comment: Only in case  you have no redundant elements. Consider using sets . As simple as that: `(set(mylist)==set([1,2,3,4,5,6]))`

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important, you can use the following code to check whether `mylist` is set to this `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

```
mylist=[6,1,2,4,3,5]

if sorted(mylist) == sorted([1,2,3,4,5,6]):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Answer (score 0):

As order is not important can't you check that all the individual elements are present?

```
>>> all([x in [1,2,3,4,5,6] for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6]])
True
>>> all([x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6]])
True
>>> all([x in [1,2,3,4,5,6] for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]])
False
```